# Open old .rpt that is prompting for a password?

Tags: database, crystal-reports

I am a healthcare provider and am changing billers for insurance claims and have requested a copy of existing data from the previous biller. The previous biller provided me with a .rpt that was created with a program called EDI Claims V64.1by EDI Healthclaims Network (antiquated program and the company is out of business).

The file is an old version of Crystal Reports and the current SAP reader did not work. I finally found a report reader that tried to open the file, but was then prompted for a password with username "admin". Previous biller does not have the password and is not sure why it is requested when trying to view the report. She also claims that there is no way to export reports in another format (excel, CSV, XML, etc) using her program. (I am skeptical of this claim, but have yet to see the program and check.) She is now saying she would have to print out the 250 page report and give me a hard copy (charging me of course), but a hard copy is not very helpful.

I am no tech flunkie, but am no programmer or database guy. I am also new in my business endeavor and the person I use for IT help is unable to help with this very important matter. If anyone has any direction or guidance about how to access the data, or someone to direct me to pay to help resolve this situation, I would be extremely grateful.
Thank you in advance.
Patrick